# How do I replace a character in a string column with another string?

Tags: sql

SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT
    adm_no,
    p.patient_id,
    patient_fname,
    patient_lname,
    to_char(round(( adm_discharge - adm_date_time ),1)) AS lenghtofstay
FROM admission ad JOIN patient p ON ad.patient_id = p.patient_id
WHERE ( adm_discharge - adm_date_time) > (select avg(adm_discharge - adm_date_time)
                                          from admission) 
and adm_discharge IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY adm_no;
```

OUTPUT

```
adm_no | patient_id | patient_fname | patient_lname | lengthofstay
-------+------------+---------------+---------------+-------------
100010 | 100110     | Abra          | Baltzar       | 7.1
```

Now I want the output to show 7.1 as 7 days and 1 hour

Comment: Have a look at [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Your question is far from clear; is `stay_period` a decimal or string? are you showing the values for 3 rows or is that a single row with a comma-delimited string??

Comment: @VanshSirohi Please edit your question to add further details instead of adding as comments.

Comment: SQL QUERY:
SELECT
    adm_no,
    p.patient_id,
    patient_fname,
    patient_lname,
    to_char(round(( adm_discharge - adm_date_time ),1),') AS lenghtofstay
FROM
         admission ad
    JOIN patient p
    ON ad.patient_id = p.patient_id
WHERE
    ( adm_discharge - adm_date_time) > (select avg( adm_discharge - adm_date_time)from admission) and
    adm_discharge IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    adm_no;

OUTTPUT

100010 100110 Abra Baltzar 7.1


Now I want the output to show 7.1 as 7 days and 1 hour

@squillman

Comment: The _Edit_ button.  Click the _Edit_ button to edit your question with more details.

Comment: @squillman question edited sir

Comment: `TO_CHAR`? Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server?

Comment: Side note: `> (select avg...` could be done better with a window function

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for something straight forward as this:

```
select '10.2', replace('10.2','.',' Days ')+' Hours'
```

or with your query:

```
select replace(YourDataColumn,'.',' Days ')+' Hours' AS lenghtofstay
```

Comment: `to_char` is not a built in function in SQL Server. Your single quotes are also incorrect.

Comment: i just copied his example query, not to fix his query, but to show what to add to it.